# How to modify a series to match indices of Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider a series `y` (`dtype` is `float64`)  which has its indices e.g.

```
y = pd.Series((6.0, 1621.0, 4.6, 1479.9, 1520.0), index=(3608, 3652, 510, 941, 3007))
```

that looks like:

```
3608       6.000
3652    1621.000
510        4.600
941     1479.900
3007    1520.000
          ...   
dtype: float64 (length: 554)
```

There is a Pandas dataframe `X` which has its own indices and multiple columns such as:

```
X = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[1,2,3], 'Col2':[1,2,3]}, index=[510,3007,3652])
```

which looks like:

```
         Col1      Col2
510
3007
3652
... (dataframe length/count is 7)
```

I would like to modify the series `y`, so as to obtain a new series that is ordered based on the dataframe indices and has same number of samples as the dataframe (i.e. 7 indices from `y` do match `X`). Expected `y` is:

```
510        4.600
3007    1520.000
3652    1621.000
          ...   
dtype: float64 (length: 7)
```

Any help and suggestions on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Chris. I tried this but am getting an error: "MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False". Thanks

Comment: sorry It's join not merge `x.join(y.rename('test'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Index.intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) method:

```
out = y[y.index.intersection(X.index)]
```

or [`Index.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) method:

```
out = y[y.index.isin(X.index)]
```

to filter `y` for indices its that also exist in `X.index`.

If `X.index` is guaranteed to be a subset of `y.index`, then you can simply filter using `X.index` as well:

```
out = y[X.index]
```

Output:

```
3652    1621.0
510        4.6
3007    1520.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score -1):

As per the question, given that the series `y` is unnamed/cannot be matched to a dataframe column name directly, the following worked:-

By converting the series `y` to a dataframe with `to_frame()` and using `X.merge()` as suggested by @Chris (thanks!) in the question's comment - alongside using the specifiers for the match to be performed on either of the indices, we can get the modified `y`

```
modified_y = X.merge(y.to_frame(), left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

This `y` is a dataframe, and can be thereby be converted back to a series form by using:-

```
modified_y = pd.Series(y.iloc[:,0].values, index = y.index)
```

There may well be easier alternatives to this, but this is how it worked for me.